# getting list of company along with employee count from another model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two model Company and Employee and have to display records like below

````
Company Name, Number of Employee

```python
class Company(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    est=models.IntegerField(max_length=4)

class employee(models.Model):
     name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
     company=models.ForeignKey(Company)
```
````

How to write Django ORM Model to fetch the detail ?

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Company.objects.values('name').annotate(emp_count=Count('employee'))
```

This will generate a `QuerySet` object as,

```
In [3]: Company.objects.values('name').annotate(emp_count=Count('employee')) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[3]: <QuerySet [{'name': 'company_name_1', 'emp_count': 3}, {'name': 'company_name_2', 'emp_count': 2}]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a **[related_name()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)** in ForeignKey Relation like this:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    est=models.IntegerField(max_length=4)

class employee(models.Model):
     name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
     company=models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='employees')
```

Then use [Count](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations) to get count from employee model and annotate the value to queryset. Like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Company.objects.annotate(employee_count=Count('employees'))  # same as related_name defined in employee model
```